# How to customize messages with static variables for push notifications (parse.com)

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

i got an application, using parse.com i established a back-end

my problem is this; is there a way to send customized push notifications based on the information i gathered?

Something like this;

`[@"Hello %@, Don't forget to brush your teeth",userName]`

or

a system that i can use the gathered data to send push notifications. for example

```
 CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo =[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc]init];
        CTCarrier *carrier =[netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];


        testUser[@"Carrier"]=[carrier carrierName];
```

I get carrier of the user like this and lets say i want to send push notification for those who use carrier A

is it possible?I tired to figure out with the apple documentations but it didn't help me.

If not with parse.com is there any system that let me do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the Parse CloudCode. Keep in mind that you can create channels, each channel in your case could be a carrier, so if the first user tries to subscribe to the channel you have to ensure that the channel exists, if not, just create it. Then you can target notifications for the channels you want from the Parse push console or from the Parse Cloud Code. It's all in the [docs](https://parse.com/docs).

So, if you're currently using Parse, to subcribe a user to the channel you can use:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"TMobile" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Then from the Parse Push console you will see that the "TMobile" channel has been added and you can send push just to the users subscribed to that channel.

Otherwise if you want to send dinamically the notifications from your webserver, you can [call a CloudFunction](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-calling) similar to this:

```
Parse.Push.send({
  channels: [ "TMobile" ],
  data: {
     alert: "Alert message"
  }
}, { success: function() { 
  // success!
  }, error: function(err) { 
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: uhmm i read a bit about CloudCode but couldn't figure it out a way to accomplish what i want.

Comment: @judge Just added some hint to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking two different questions.

For the first question, [Apple Push Notifications support this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW21).

> ...the client application can store in its bundle the alert-message
>   strings translated for each localization it supports. The provider
>   specifies the loc-key and loc-args properties in the aps dictionary of
>   the notification payload. When the device receives the notification
>   (assuming the application isn’t running), it uses these aps-dictionary
>   properties to find and format the string localized for the current
>   language, which it then displays to the user.
>
> Here’s how that second option works in a little more detail.
>
> An application can internationalize resources such as images, sounds,
>   and text for each language that it supports, Internationalization
>   collects the resources and puts them in a subdirectory of the bundle
>   with a two-part name: a language code and an extension of .lproj (for
>   example, fr.lproj). Localized strings that are programmatically
>   displayed are put in a file called Localizable.strings. Each entry in
>   this file has a key and a localized string value; the string can have
>   format specifiers for the substitution of variable values. When an
>   application asks for a particular resource—say a localized string—it
>   gets the resource that is localized for the language currently
>   selected by the user. For example, if the preferred language is
>   French, the corresponding string value for an alert message would be
>   fetched from Localizable.strings in the fr.lproj directory in the
>   application bundle. (The application makes this request through the
>   NSLocalizedString macro.)
>
> To make this clearer, let’s consider an example. The provider
>   specifies the following dictionary as the value of the alert property:

```
{"aps" : 
  {"alert" : {
    "loc-key" : "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT",
    "loc-args" : [ "Jenna", "Frank"]
  }
}
```

> When the device receives the notification, it uses
>   "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT" as a key to look up the associated string
>   value in the Localizable.strings file in the .lproj directory for the
>   current language. Assuming the current localization has an
>   Localizable.strings entry such as this:
>
> "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT" = "%@ and %@ have invited you to play
>   Monopoly";
>
> the device displays an alert with the message “Jenna and Frank have
>   invited you to play Monopoly”.
>
> In addition to the format specifier %@, you can %n$@ format specifiers
>   for positional substitution of string variables. The n is the index
>   (starting with 1) of the array value in loc-args to substitute.
>   (There’s also the %% specifier for expressing a percentage sign (%).)
>   So if the entry in Localizable.strings is this:
>
> "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT" = "%2$@ and %1$@ have invited you to play
>   Monopoly";
>
> the device displays an alert with the message “Frank and Jenna have
>   invited you to play Monopoly”.

Comment: well first of all thank for this explanation, but i there is a problem in what you are trying.

What i need or want to do is can not be done in locally.

I will send push notifications from the back-end without any triggers came from the program.

in your example it looks for GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT where he finds users, which is not useful in my case

Comment: @judge Well, that's the only way you can have parameters in the message displayed in iOS devices when a push notification arrives. All the parameter values must sent from the server. The only thing that can be taken from the device is the localized string whose key you are sending in `loc-key`.

Comment: thats the thing that leads this idea to me.You are right, i m sending this global push notification via server, but the things is this is where i have all the needed data.I got each and their carriers why can't i send a static notification?